# Getting the view to mimic the image below using HTML5

Tags: html, css

I want to get buttons style as shown in picture, so I need to know how to get those type of buttons using HTML5 and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="topLeft"></div>
    <div class="topRight"></div>
    <div class="botLeft"></div>
    <div class="botRight"></div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
.wrap {width: 515px; padding: 20px; margin: auto;}
.wrap div {width: 150px; height: 150px; background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #ccc;}

div.topLeft {border-radius: 50px 15px 15px 15px;}
div.topRight {border-radius: 15px 50px 15px 15px;}
div.botLeft {border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 50px;}
div.botRight {border-radius: 15px 15px 50px 15px;}​
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Preview]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fBTxw/1/

Comment: @androidphonegap Is this approach fine?

Comment: yah thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular `div` elements that are styled with the CSS [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) property, where you apply a radius to just one of the four corners on each `div`. You can then apply a [CSS gradient](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient) to the background.